# Will it cause a memory leak if I create a new array each time I read from a Serial Port in Win Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have a WinForms project that I'm modifying which opens a serial port and then reads from the port when a message is there. I have a guaranteed rate of 1 Hz, with messages possibly arriving more quickly than this.  If I create a new array into which the data is read each time the event fires, will this cause a memory leak or is this array garbage collected after the function completes execution?  I'm talking about the `buffer` array below. Do I need to release the array resources in any way?

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort();
_serialPort.DataReceived += OnPortDataReceived
_portData = new List<bytes>();

void OnPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    int bytes = sp.BytesToRead;
    if (bytes > 0)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        _portData.AddRange(buffer);

        // Process the list of bytes
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything. This is a common idiom.

Comment: It's more optimal to reuse the same array (and use `.Take(bytesRead)` to pass only the valid portion to `AddRange`).  You should check the return value of `Read()`.  Also you are missing a lock, right now you could have multiple threads writing to `_portData` at the same time which would definitely break things.

Comment: In general you would be better off doing async/await than handling `DataReceived`.

Comment: It will do, don't bother. You will become middle developer before you encounter any memory leaks you can fix.

Comment: Wouldn't call it a *leak*, just an inefficient use of memory. All arrays will be cleaned up *eventually*.

Comment: It won't leak, but Array allocations aren't exactly performant (neither is the eventual garbage collection), so if you're dealing with high-speed comms with lots of data, it will be quite noticeable. The suggestion to *reuse the same array* is a good one. Or an `ArrayPool` if you need to do it in many places across your code.

Comment: @NPras I don't think that any data received via serial can be enough to bother the garbage collector noticeably. While it might be a good exercice to do it _right_, something that creates like 100kb/s of garbage is just irrelevant.

Comment: @PMF you'd be surprised. There's many industrial Serial-to-USB and Serial-to-ethernet devices with drivers that present themselves as Windows virtual comports, and gives you multi-megabit speeds.